# In Vue, how do I pass the special $event variable as a paremeter?

Tags: vue.js, events, event-handling

In Vue, I'm listening for a change event and trying to pass in the special $event variable to an action like this:

```
<template>
<div>
      <span>Filter Todos:</span>
      <select @change="filterTodos($event)">
```

In my action I've just got this for now:

```
filterTodos(event) {
        console.log('Here is the event:', event);
    }
```

When the Brad Traversy in my tutorial does this, he gets the Event in his console. But when I do it, I'm getting this:

```
{getters: {…}, state: {…}, rootGetters: {…}, dispatch: ƒ, commit: ƒ, …}
commit: ƒ boundCommit(type, payload, options)
dispatch: ƒ boundDispatch(type, payload)
getters: {}
rootGetters: {}
rootState: {__ob__: Observer}
state: {__ob__: Observer}
__proto__: Object
```

What am I getting there? Why aren't I getting the same as him?
No one else in the comments section seems to have a problem with this so I must be doing something silly but I can't spot it...

Comment: The bug is probably not coming from the snippets you showed us but from the event emitted by the select.

Answer (score 0):

Since your `filterTodos` has only one parameter which is actually the event you want, it is not compulsory to pass `$event` in your template. instead, you can just pass the method name as following,

```
<template>
<div>
      <span>Filter Todos:</span>
      <select @change="filterTodos" />
</div>
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks Vikum! That makes complete sense now. And if I want my action to call a mutation then I can use { commit } as my first parameter and 'event' as my second parameter. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I realise the fault now... I can't have that parameter 'event' as the only parameter in my filterTodos action. If I do the following then it works and I get the event in my console...

```
filterTodos({ commit }, event) {
    console.log('Here is the event:', event);
    commit('testForNow');
}
```

So the first parameter (in this case, { commit }) of an action relates to whatever mutation I'll be doing later in the tutorial in relation to that action. 'event' needs to be my second parameter, even though '$event' is the only argument when I call this action.